# Hide Statusbar in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-titlebar

I'm trying to hide status bar in fragment.
I have successfully hidden toolbar but I want to hide status bar also only in one fragment..

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);

   // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
```

Above code working fine for hide toolbar

```
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

If I `requestWindowFeature` in fragment `onCreate` (has mentioned above)  application was crashed.

**Added three screenshots after implementing answer by @Mathan Chinna**

1. Normal Screen

[image: Normal Screen]

2. After implementing the code from @Mathan Chinna

[image: code from mathan chinna]

3. When I come back from full screen

[image: When I come back from full screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Lalit Singh Fauzdar answer to hide statusBar is correct. if u want to show statusBar u can use

```java
View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView(); // Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Answer (score 8):

Just a copy-paste from my project though but this way you can hide the status bar in a fragment.

```
 private int currentApiVersion;       
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN    
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
            final View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
    }
```

DO remember that this code is to be copied in your Fragment class and not in any method.

And yes, you could have used only the below code:

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: thanks! your codes works for MarshMallow .... for my concerns for lower and higher version i want to ask u that ...will this work for 15 api to 27 api?

Comment: and how to show statusBar Again? i m unable to show it agian for another fragment.
see three pics i have edited que

Comment: I get a grey statusbar when I use the code you suggested.. Not a fullscreen image..

Comment: Yeah I am also getting a grey status bar

Comment: Doesnt work for me (API 30) it makes status bar white

Comment: Even I get white status bar.. How to fix this?

Answer (score -2):

I hope you this code is help you more..

From Activity...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // YOUR FRAGMENT
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment,fragment.toString());
   fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
public void HideStatusBar() {
   this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  }
public void ShowStatusBar() {
    this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  }
}
```

from fragment..

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

private Activity mActivity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


 ((MainActivity) getActivity()).HideStatusBar();
   }
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.mActivity = activity;

}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    this.mActivity = null;
}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (mActivity!=null){
       ((MainActivity) getActivity()).ShowStatusBar();
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: HideStatusBar() i have tocall this method from fragment onCreate?

Comment: if you think that my answer is helped you, please consider accepting it. thank you !

Comment: your codes only  hide actionbar .....  and this thing i can achieve by.getActionBar().hide();